# .htaccess Authentication Internal Server Error 500

Tags: ubuntu, authentication, .htaccess, htpasswd

I am trying to setup an authentication for a directory on a ubuntu server and when i sign in i get a 500 Internal Server Error

I have the following:

```
 AuthUserFile .htpasswd
 AuthName "Sign In"
 AuthType Basic
 Require eMA
```

I also tried the POST GET and valid-user

the htpaswd file is in the same directory as the htaccess.

I cant seem to figure out what would be causing this any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you use apache webserver. Most probably you will find the cause of the error in the error_log file which can be found in /var/log/apache2 according to http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DistrosDefaultLayout.

Comment: +1 I bet AllowOverrides isn't properly set.

Answer (score -1):

AuthUserFile /app/seguridad/.htpasswd
AuthName "Area Protegida"
AuthType Basic

require user francisco

Para solucionar tuve que editar el siguiente archivo
vim /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
Y agregar la siguientes lineas:
33 LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
34 LoadModule auth_digest_module modules/mod_auth_digest.so
35 LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so

Y listo!
Solucionado.
Espero haberte ayudado.
Saludos,
Francisco.

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault.  We greatly prefer answers to be in English.  Don't worry if your English language skills aren't great; I'll bet you're better at English than I am at Spanish.  (grin)